# why my INSERT INTO method returns false?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, insert

I'm trying to insert some information to one of my db tables. here is my code:

```
function insertUser(){
    $con = db_connect();
    $response = array();

    if(empty($_REQUEST['firstname'])){
        $fnam = "";
    }else{
        $fnam = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
    }

    if(empty($_REQUEST['lastname'])){
        $lnam = "";
    }else{
        $lnam = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
    }

    if(empty($_REQUEST['age'])){
        $age = "";
    }else{
        $age = $_REQUEST['age'];
    }

    if(empty($_REQUEST['sex'])){
        $sex = "";
    }else{
        $sex = $_REQUEST['sex'];
    }

    if(empty($_REQUEST['location'])){
        $loc = "";
    }else{
        $loc = $_REQUEST['location'];
    }

    if(empty($_REQUEST['education'])){
        $edu = "";
    }else{
        $edu = $_REQUEST['education'];
    }

   //check if username forgot
    if(empty($_REQUEST['username'])){
        $response[] = "Please fill username box";
    }else{
        $uname = $_REQUEST['username'];
        //check if username is existed
        $isExisted = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = '$uname'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($isExisted) > 0){
            $response[] = "Username is Existed";
            }
         }

    //check if password forgot
    if(empty($_REQUEST['password'])){
        $response[] = "Please fill password box";
    } else{
        $pass = $_REQUEST['password'];
    }

    if(empty($response)){
        //$password = getHash($password);
        $res = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tbl_users (firstnam, lastname, age, sex, location, education, username, password, created_at) VALUES ('$fnam', '$lnam', '$age', '$sex', '$loc', '$edu', '$uname', '$pass', NOW())");
        // user stored successfully
        if ($res) {
            $response[] = "user stored successfully";
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

and here is the connection to my db that I can read data using this:

```
function db_connect(){
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ketabha");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    return $con;
}
```

table name and every column name is correct but it dose not work! and when I `echo json_encode($res);` it is showing false in my browser. can you help me please?

Comment: `false` means the query got an error. Use `echo mysqli_error($con)` to see the error message.

Comment: Instead of using `echo json_encode($res);`, you should be using `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to get the "real" error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php wouldn't hurt neither.

Comment: You should use `bind_param()` instead of variable substitution. Probably one of the variables contains a quote, and it's causing a syntax error.

Comment: @Barmar I did what you said to me and here is the result in my browser. I entered passwrod as jakf\. 
Erreur de syntaxe près de ''jakf\', NOW())' à la ligne 1

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, I got the error as Erreur de syntaxe près de ''jakf\', NOW())' à la ligne 1. jakf\ is the password.

Comment: Escape your data or better yet, use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). That will fix it. Good thing I understand French, mais oui mon ami ;)

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly I must to do for this error plus I'm not French! I dont know why the language of my db is this! @Fred-ii- thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Now, for the language thing; probably because the `.ini` file for the SQL is set to something like `lc-messages=fr_FR` which needs to be changed to `lc-messages=en_GB`. @NiloofarHakkaki If you're running on Wamp, then that is most likely why. I too was faced with the same problem.

Comment: In the meantime, you can use `stripslashes()` and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to get you started.

Comment: the problem is with NOW(). dose not php know this function to get now time and date? and one more thing, Yes I have wamp, then wamp is french? @Fred-ii-

Comment: @NiloofarHakkaki Strangely enough, yes it was made by someone in France. As for the `NOW()` function, what seems to be the problem? You didn't say what it's doing or not doing. `NOW()` is a built-in SQL function. Your `created_at` should be as `DATETIME`.

Comment: ok it works! thanks every body. look at my code! I REQUEST for firstname but in INSERT INTO I wrote firstnam:) @Fred-ii-

Comment: I actually thought at the beginning that you may have mispelled the word `firstnam`, I should have said something lol if you want the question closed, I can make it an answer. After all, I worked pretty hard ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- tank you and good french people!:)

Comment: @NiloofarHakkaki You're welcome and was glad to have helped and solved this for you. I posted my answer below which can now be marked as solved, *cheers*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple comments to answer in order to close the question and be marked as solved:

Escape your data using both [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) and [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) functions.

Better yet, use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

This amongst many comments exchanged throughout a period of time, such as your `created_at` column to be as `DATETIME` for your `NOW()` MySQL function.

Another is what I thought being a mispelled column name, being `firstnam` which I suspected to be `firstname`.

In regards to the French language errors; this is because the `.ini` file for the SQL is set to something like `lc-messages=fr_FR` which needs to be changed to `lc-messages=en_GB`, since you are using [**Wampserver**](http://www.wampserver.com/), is what needs to be done in order to get to get messages in English.

Wamp's default language is set to French in its MySQL, *strangely enough*.

Instead of using `echo json_encode($res);`, you should be using `or die(mysqli_error($con))` in order to get the "real" error.

You can then resort back to using `echo json_encode($res);` once you have bug-free code.

Comment: I couldn't found the problem without that function , many thanks to you and Barmar.

Comment: @NiloofarHakkaki A little (and humorous) guide on SQL Injection: http://bobby-tables.com I suggest you read it to fully understand why Fred's recommendation on using prepared statements is really a gooooooooood idea